# How do I get the list of all images on a page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Firefox, I can get a list of all images from the "Media" tab of the [Page Info window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-page-info-window):

[image: Firefox Page Info window]

How can I obtain such a list using Python Selenium? In addition to getting such a list of image URLs, I would also like to be able to get each image's data (i.e. the image itself) without needing to make additional network requests.

Please DO NOT suggest that I parse the HTML to look for `<img ... />` tags. That is clearly not what I'm looking for. I am looking for image responses. Not all image responses are present in the DOM. Example: some image responses from AJAX requests.

Comment: can you share a link so i can inspect the page?

Comment: @SMJune Sorry, I don't understand your comment. My example screenshot shows https://stackoverflow.com, but I'm asking for a general method (i.e. one that will work across a wide variety of pages) to get all images on a page. I'm looking for a programmatic analog to what Firefox provides through its GUI.